# gtkmm build error using autotools

Tags: gnome, gtk, autotools, gnome-builder

I've started to learn gtkmm programming, but am stuck at the first step. I'm using GNOME builder IDE and Ubuntu 17.10 64bit.

Gnome has a [nice tutorial for gtkmm](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en), but building the code returns an error in builder!

**Problem:**
According to the tutorial, the source code must be compiled by g++, while builder uses gcc, since the file name is `main.c`.

```
mohammad@Artful-K43SD:~/Projects/test/src$ g++ main.c -o simple `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` -no-pie
mohammad@Artful-K43SD:~/Projects/test/src$ gcc main.c -o simple `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` -no-pie
In file included from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:21:0,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/exception.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/error.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/thread.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h:88,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:87,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/unicode.h:26:10: fatal error: cctype: No such file or directory
 #include <cctype>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

---

```
make V=0 -j4 all
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mohammad/.cache/gnome-builder/builds/test/default-local-host'
Making all in data
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mohammad/.cache/gnome-builder/builds/test/default-local-host/data'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mohammad/.cache/gnome-builder/builds/test/default-local-host/data'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mohammad/.cache/gnome-builder/builds/test/default-local-host/src'
  CC       test-main.o
In file included from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:21:0,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/exception.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/error.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/thread.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h:88,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:87,
                 from /home/mohammad/Projects/test/src/main.c:1:
/usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/unicode.h:26:10: fatal error: cctype: No such file or directory
 #include <cctype>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [test-main.o] Error 1
Makefile:481: recipe for target 'test-main.o' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mohammad/.cache/gnome-builder/builds/test/default-local-host/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:477: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mohammad/.cache/gnome-builder/builds/test/default-local-host'
Makefile:409: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I just want to tell autotools to use g++ for `.c` files instead of gcc. tried edit the `configure.ac` file in the project folder, but I wasn't successful! The makefile is generated by builder and if I add a `.cpp` file to project, the makefile won't update!

Is it possible to code gtkmm in builder?

Comment: Do you really *need* to call the file `main.c` - rather than (for example) `main.cc` or `main.cpp`? it seems like you are making things harder than they need to be.

Comment: like I said, for every .cc or .cpp files, I have to change makefile and some configurations, and builder(GNOME Application autotools) generate makefile with .c file :(